# Problema al insertar un campo en sql cundo las tablas estan relacionadas

Tags: sql

tengo dos tablas combinadas, para dar un ejemplo en tengo los datos de los clientes en los cuales entre ellos esta el sexo id_sexo

y en la otra tablea tengo id_sexo 1 = masculino 2 femenino.

si cuando ingreso el formulario omito elejir el sexo de las personas osea el inser para sexo viene vacio, me tira un error de fallo de conexion con el sql.

como puedo hacer para cuando haya dos tablas combinadas, me deje en la tabla madre poner un valor vacio?

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: habria que ver como tenes definida la tabla.. pero tiene que aceptar nulos en ese campo

Comment: Pero si es un fallo de **conexión** no creo que tenga que ver con las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por sus comentarios, lo resolvi en sql poniendo un valor por defecto y creando ese valor en la tabla, ejemplo, si el usuario no selecciona el sexo en la tabla sexo puse un valor por default que si viene vacio ponga id 3 = seleccionar.

muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo